# Setting gradle version property via text file causes question mark in JAR

Tags: gradle

Using gradle 2.10. I have this in my build.gradle

`version = file('src/main/resources/VERSION').text`

The contents of `src/main/resources/VERSION` is `0.1.0`.

When I build the jar I get a file named `myapp-0.1.0?.jar`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove `"` from the `VERSION` file.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't actually have quotes in the file. I've updated my original question.

Comment: Maybe there's a *strange* sign at the end of the `VERSION` file. Could you please verify it?

Comment: The best idea is to verify it with a binary editor.

Comment: that was it, i had a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Opal I found that the file had a newline which didn't show up when editing in vi. Removing the trailing newline took care of the question mark showing up in the jar/tar file names.